# Настройка сервера git?

Tags: linux, windows, git

Есть следующее - рабочий комп Win 7, netbeans, связь с сервером по winscp, putty, OpenServer.
Сервер - centos
Хочу получить следующее - на сервере постоянно рабочий проект. При необходимости что-то исправить я на локальной тачке кодю и тестю. После чего заливаю на сервер.
Или в таком случае можно обойтись без локалки и просто на сервере держать две ветки - основная и develop ?
Очень смутное представление как оно должно работать. Git где создает репозитарий? Запущенный проект и репозитарий - одно и то же?
Сейчас процесс разработки такой - локально допиливаю функции, в случае чего заливаю на сервак и смотрю как на нем запустилось.

### UPD

чисто практический вопрос. создал репозитарий на сервере. пытаюсь подключиться из нетбинса. использовать протокол http или ssh? пароль рута? если проект yii лежит в var/www/sitename/public_html/yiiproj . в yiiproj создан реп .git
как подключиться? как sitename/yiiproj/.git или sitename/public_html/yiiproj/.git

Comment: вот вам только что написали - на вашем живом сервере не должно быть репозитория. вы вообще ответы читаете?

Comment: а ну сначала сделал. потом прочитал

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По *изначальному* же вопросу я скажу так - основной репозиторий должен быть на **дев**-тачке. А на боевом сервере репозиториев **вообще быть не должно,** при любых раскладах. На боевом должен быть только сам гит, который цепляется к репозиторию, и выливает код. Репозиторий нужен только там, где с ним работают.

То есть,

- здесь мы имеем систему с единственным репозиторием.
- вопрос пуша снимается (его нет)
- разработка ведется в ветке (dev)
- после того как ветка оттестирована, она вливается (merge) в мастер
- на сервере после этого делается что-то вроде git archive чтобы вылить обновленный код. это можно делать как системой деплоя так и руками.

Кстати, я тут прогнал. Последний пункт ведь невыполним, скорее всего.  Это с выделенного дев-сервера продакшен может спокойно утянуть код, а на локальную винду-то очень вряд ли открыты входящие.

Так что деплой, пожалуй, делать дедовским способом - архивом. Ну, или какой-нибудь специальной деплоилкой. Получается, что на продакшен гит даже устанавливать не надо.

Для ответов на остальные вопросы, которые возникают у автора, ему надо просто открыть мануал, в котором есть все ответы. И про то "где создает репозиторий?" (это, как бы, ключевое отличие гита от других систем контроля версий - везде) и "главное не коммитить?" (если понять, что система распределенная, то станет ясно, что коммитить можно и нужно. Не нужно неоттестированную ветку пушить), и совсем уж вопросы из мануала "я могу откатиться, посмотреть изменения?" (а для чего еще нужна скв?)

Comment: нет ну я ж спрашиваю про иделогоию. и уже почти понял все

Comment: я как понимаю вы про систему деплоя что то вроде capistrano ?

Answer (score 2):

Git - это децентрализованная система. Эт осводится к тому, что удаленный репоизторий и репозиторий на вашем компьютере **абсолютно равноценны**. Когда вы делаете пуш, вы не "обновляете сервер", вы пересылаете обновления из одного репозитория в другой. Нет, без локального репозитория не получится, потому что иначе как вы будете пересылать.

Comment: то есть будет локальный реп для тестовой ветки и серверный для мастера?

Comment: Нет, будут два идентичных репозитория.

Comment: ну это после пуша. а так то локально ломай не хочу, главное неоттестированный код не коммитить. я правильно понимаю? а как же контроль версий? там вроде как откатиться можно? или я путаю?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, о чем речь. Один коммит - это слепок проекта в конкретный момент времени. К нему всегда можно откатиться. То, что не было записано в коммит - к нему откатиться нельзя.

Comment: так а пуш? это синхронизация локали и сервера?

Comment: в общем рабочий процесс - есть сервер. пришла заявка допилить функционал. я себе клонирую проект. коммичу (т.е. сохраняюю до изменений). на локалке добавляю фунционал. пушу на сервер - все упало - откатываю к последнему коммиту. все ок - коммичу этот новый проект. я все правильно понимаю?

Comment: Еще раз: гит - это децентрализованная система. Это не синхронизация, это пересылка выбранного набора коммитов, никто не грантирует, что после пуша содержимое будет идентичным (хотя в этом случае - будет). Коммит делается только после того, как появилось что-то новое, поэтому до изменений у вас просто не получится сделать коммит. В остальном - да, все верно.

Answer (score 1):

отвечу на один из вопросов:

> Git где создает репозитарий?

`git init` (без параметра `--bare`) и `git clone` создают репозиторий в подкаталоге `.git`.

`git init --bare` создаёт репозиторий непосредственно в указанном каталоге.

«опознать» git-репозиторий можно по наличию примерно такого списка файлов и каталогов:

```
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Comment: в общем мне нужно на сервере в папке с проектом прописать git init, а затем локально подцепиться и склонировать к себе на тачку. там что хочу то ворочу, затем пушу на сервер новую версию? а про контроль версий - я могу откатиться, посмотреть изменения?

Comment: 1. после инициализации репозитория надо добавить файлы (`git add ...`) и создать коммит (`git commit ...`), остальное верно. 2.  да, конечно, после создания как минимум двух коммитов можно переключать содержимое `working tree` (файлы и каталоги, входящие в репозиторий) на тот или другой коммит. и, конечно, можно смотреть изменения, внесённые любым коммитом.

Comment: рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией. например, [почитав git-book](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

> чисто практический вопрос. создал репозитарий на сервере. пытаюсь подключиться из нетбинса. использовать протокол http или ssh?

для обращения по любому из протоколов нужен, как минимум, установленный и настроенный сервер. в случае использования протокола `ssh` у вас на серверной машине, скорее всего, уже есть всё необходимое: работающий `sshd`.

> пароль рута?

подключать удалённый репозиторий по протоколу `ssh` следует:

- от имени пользователя, имеющего как минимум доступ на чтение к репозиторию, в случае, если не планируется отправлять в этот репозиторий изменения;
- от имени пользователя, имеющего права на запись файлов репозитория, в случае, если планируется отравлять в этот репозиторий изменения.

пароль, естественно, должен соответствовать выбранному пользователю. в общем, всё, как и при «стандартном» подключении по протоколу `ssh`.

> если проект yii лежит в var/www/sitename/public_html/yiiproj . в yiiproj создан реп .git как подключиться? как sitename/yiiproj/.git или sitename/public_html/yiiproj/.git

схема та же, что и при использовании, например, `scp` или `sshfs`. примерно так:

```
$ git clone пользователь@sitename:/var/www/sitename/public_html/yiiproj
```

p.s. насколько я понимаю правила и рекомендации этого сайта, дополнительные «глобальные» вопросы имеет смысл задавать отдельно, а не в виде правок текста исходного вопроса.