# Не проходит git push, нет файлов в удаленном репозитарии

Tags: git

Приветствую!
Создал удаленный репозитарий `git --bare init grid`. На локальной машине создаю папку `grid` и в ней выполняю команду `git init`. Затем добавлю удаленный репозитарий `git remote add origin ssh ****` и затем `git clone ssh:`
Далее, создаю файлы которые будут в проекте и выполняю коммит и выполняю `git push origin master`

> Counting objects: 5, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.03 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   To ssh://g******
>   * [new branch] master -> master

Однако зайдя по ssh на удаленный репозитарий, файлов в проекте нет. Что не так у меня, я что-то проспутил?

Comment: вы видите там то же самое (ну, за мелкими отличиями), что и в каталоге `.git` на своей локальной машине. **это и есть** репозиторий (хранилище). и тех файлов, которые вы создали в рабочем каталоге, вы там не найдёте (по крайней мере, в том виде, в каком они присутствуют в рабочем каталоге).

Comment: гуглить на тему "git bare repo"

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542434/178576 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571584/178576 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428062/178576

Comment: Да, пожалуй вы правы. Я до этого cvs использовал, там файлы явно видны.